# Error in Audio recorder and play in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

When I run below code, I get this error `Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1718449215 "(null)"
Error in prepare audio recorder
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1718449215 "(null)"
Error in prepare audio recorder`

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var recordAoutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var playOutlet: UIButton!

    var audioRecorder:AVAudioRecorder!
    var audioPLayer:AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.prepareAudioRecorder()

    }

    @IBAction func recorderAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if !audioRecorder.isRecording {
            //Start Recorder
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            do{
                try audioSession.setActive(true)
                audioRecorder.record()
            } catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                print("error in recorder action 1")
                }

        } else {
            //Stop Recorder
            audioRecorder.stop()
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

            do{
                try audioSession.setActive(false)
            }catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                print("error in recorder action 2")

            }
            //check
            if self.verifyFileExists() {
                print("file exixts")
                playOutlet.isHidden = false
            } else {
                print("there was a problem recording.")
            }
        }
        self.updateRecorderbuttonTitle()
    }


    @IBAction func playAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.playAudio()
    }
    //MARK: main
    func prepareAudioRecorder() {
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
            try audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: self.audioFileLocation()), settings: self.audioSettings())
            audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            print("Error in prepare audio recorder")
        }

    }

    func playAudio(){
        let audioSession =  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try audioPLayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath:self.audioFileLocation()))
            audioPLayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPLayer.play()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            print("error in audio session func")
        }

    }

    // MARK:Helper
    func audioFileLocation()-> String {
        return NSTemporaryDirectory().appending("AudioRecording.mp4")
    }

    func audioSettings()->[String:Any] {
        let settings = [AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber.init(value: kAudioFormatAppleLossless),
                        AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber.init(value: 44100.0),
                        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber.init(value: 1),
                        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey : NSNumber.init(value: 16),
                        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber.init(value: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue)]
        return settings
    }

    // update buttons titles

    func updateRecorderbuttonTitle(){
        if audioRecorder.isRecording {
            recordAoutlet.setTitle("Recording...", for:.normal)
        } else {
            recordAoutlet.setTitle("Record", for: .normal)
        }
    }

    // Verify File Exists
    func verifyFileExists()-> Bool{
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        return fileManager.fileExists(atPath: self.audioFileLocation())
    }
}
```